# Update state using dynamic key and value by using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update dynamic key and value to current state array and output should be like this.

```
0: {1,10}
1:{2,0}
3:{3,14}
```

Here 1,10 && 2,0 && 3,14 are dynamic key and value

Comment: please provide more info and the correct format of array/object that you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need to add dynamic key and value to a state array only.... whenever a new value came, it will be appended to the previous array. Currently i don't have a format. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by the following solution

```
 const arrayList = viewRecordCount;
 arrayList.push({ [viewId]: response.data.viewResultCount })
 setViewRecordCount({ records: arrayList })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [myState, setState] = useState([]);
  console.log(myState)
  
  const a = 'Your key value'
  const b = 'your value'

  const handleClick = (a,b) => {
    setState((prevState) => [...myState, {[a]: b }]);
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(a, b)}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zanetti...  I need to add each result to a state array.
Your solution only adding one dynamic key value

Comment: Hi Mahesh, I had just edited my answer. I hope it helps.